# Angular js watchexpression cacth new element

Tags: arrays, angularjs

my question is really simple but after a lot of searching I couldn't find an answer.  Is there any way to watch an array for changes and fire a function when a new element is added, where the element is consoled for example.

$watchExpression works fine when a new element is pushed in an array but it doesn't provide any info about the element that is added. I was thinking of implementing a function that has two variables, one that contains the array before adding the new element and another variable that holds the new state of the array and compare them ,so I could find the element added but this solution seems very unclean and inefficient. Is there any better solution?

Thx in advance

I tried this:

```
$scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];

$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, old) {
  console.log(newNames);
  console.log(old);
});

$scope.names.push("john");
```

but the output is this:

> ["igor", "matias", "misko", "james", "john"]
>
> ["igor", "matias", "misko", "james", "john"]

Comment: you can't use new as name for a variable. EDIT: i didn't see you edited already

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's _.difference.

https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

```
$scope.$watch('scopeToWatch', function(newVal, oldVal){
var changed;
changed = lodash.difference(oldVal, newVal);
console.log(changed);
})
```

If you want to see if an item was added or removed, do this:

```
        $scope.$watch('scopeToWatch', function(newVal, oldVal){
    var change;
    if(newVal.length>oldVal.length){
    change = 'added';
    } else if(newVal.length<oldVal.length) {
    change = 'removed';
    } else {
    change = 'none'
    }

        var changed;
        changed = lodash.difference(oldVal, newVal);
if(change !== 'none'){
        console.log(changed+ 'was '+ change);
} else {
        console.log('no change');

}
    })
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but I cannot adapt your example to my test-case. I cannot find any documentation about lodash.difference function so I am confused on how to use it.

Comment: After trial and error I managed to do make it work, but the result s the same as mine. Both oldval and newVal have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The only efficient solution i can come up with is to overwrite the push function for the given array. Of course you can apply this as well to things like .concat etc depending on what you need.
Of course you can also refactor this overwriting process into a function/service for a better code style. This is just for demonstration purposes:

```
var x = [1,2,3];  // define the initial array
x._push = x.push; // "backup" the normal push function
x.push = function () {
    x._push(a);   // do the normal push
    console.log ('added: ' + a); // do your magic here...
};

x.push (4);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thx for your answer. What you suggest works for the example I posted in the question but in many cases the handling of the array isn't from the user. So I am more interested in a solution with a watcher.

Comment: what do you mean by the handlng of the array isn't from the user ?
when you overwrite the corresponding push function you will always be informed when a new entry is pushed to the array. it doesn't matter where in the code the array is changed (even in external libraries which call the .push function on that array)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your output is that the browser console doesn't log a copy of your array but just the reference of the array asynchronously.
When you open the array in the console afterwards (assuming the developer console of Google-Chrome for example) it will show the elements which it contains at the point of inspecting it instead of the elements it had when it was officially logged.
What you can do to avoid this is to log a copy of the arrays instead.
So the problem is actually the console.log function itself, not your code.
Try

```
console.log (old.slice());
```

instead of

```
console.log (old);
```

This makes a copy of your array hence the array should be logged as-is since it won't be changed afterwards.